# How to show Lottie animation in Splash Screen of Android?

Tags: android, splash-screen, lottie

I used Lottie Animation inside the App. No issue with that.

But **is it even possible to use it in Splash Screen?** Now my splash screen **has a Launcher theme that persists only the cold start duration**.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launcher_with_logo</item> <!--Also available: @drawable:launcher_screen_with_background-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I want to do something like this [Splash Screen of Crane provided by Google's Material Design Guideline](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/44372c226d5735a8cc277237d4a152a0553fd2dc9394f0627d0ba0f31698af86eb6944428c288e94992c318bcb350b6d0c0cfd7930abb86594a318440f5fbcdc).

So is there any way to do this by satisfying standard guidelines to create a splash screen(just show during cold start rather than setting a timer, which is ugly)?

same questions also asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783132/lottie-animation-in-native-android-splash-screen)